# Hide popover in onsen ui

Tags: angularjs, popover, onsen-ui

So before someone jumps on me and shout that there is already a solution for this, I'm sorry but it doesn't work for me.
I had a look and tried both options proposed in the questions bellow, with no success.
[How to hide popover in onsen ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713320/how-to-hide-popover-in-onsen-ui)

I don't really understand why as my code is almost identical to the examples. I use a sliding menu on the page but that's pretty much it.

Here is my index.html

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sliding_menu.css">
<script>

    var app = ons.bootstrap('propertyDeal', ['onsen']);
    app.controller('AppController', function($scope, myService) {
        ons.createPopover('popover.html',{parentScope: $scope}).then(function(popover) {
            $scope.popover = popover;
            myService.setPopover($scope.popover);
        });
    })
    app.controller('HydePController', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.destroyPopover = function() {
            $scope.popover = myService.getPopover();    
            $scope.popover.hide();
        }
    });

    app.service("myService", function(){
        var sharedPopover

        var setPopover = function(pop){
            sharedPopover = pop;
        };

        var getPopover = function(){
            return sharedPopover;
        };

        return {
            setPopover: setPopover,
            getPopover: getPopover,
        };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="initial.html" menu-page="menu.html" max-slide-distance="260px" type="overlay" var="menu" side="left" close-on-tap>
</ons-sliding-menu>
<ons-template id="popover.html">
    <ons-popover direction="down" cancelable>
            <ons-list ng-controller="HydePController">
                <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('save.html', {closeMenu: true}); popover.hide()">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-cloud"></ons-icon>
                    Save property
                </ons-list-item>
                <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="hydepopover()">
                    <ons-icon icon="fa-home"></ons-icon>
                    View portfolio
                </ons-list-item>
            </ons-list>
    </ons-popover>

</ons-template>

</body>
```

And initial.html

```
<ons-navigator>
<ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
        <ons-icon class="icon" icon="ion-social-usd"></ons-icon>&nbsp;Initial investment
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-android-share" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
        </ons-toolbar-button>
            <ons-toolbar-button ng-controller="AppController" id="android-more" ng-click="popover.show($event);">
              <ons-icon icon="ion-android-more" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
            </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h2>Initial investment</h2>

        <ul class="list">
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Purchase price">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Market value">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Stamp duty">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Sourcing fee">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Legal fee">
            </li>
            <li class="list__item">
                <input type="text" class="text-input text-input--transparent" style="width:100%; margin-top:4px;" placeholder="Other">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        </ul>
    </div>

</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

So as said above, I tried both solutions and no luck. I don't understand why. I also have the sliding menu that doesn't close when clicking outside of the menu. Could this be related ?

Thank you for your help !
Arnaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is fine except one small mistake. You should not add the controller on `ons-toolbar-button` because it will break the button.

Just add the controller on the parent element (in `initial.html`), from this:

```html
<div class="right">
   <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-android-share" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
   </ons-toolbar-button>
   <ons-toolbar-button ng-controller="AppController" id="android-more" ng-click="popover.show($event);">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-android-more" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
   </ons-toolbar-button>
</div>
```

to this:

```html
<div class="right" ng-controller="AppController" >
   <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggleMenu()">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-android-share" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
   </ons-toolbar-button>
   <ons-toolbar-button id="android-more" ng-click="popover.show($event);">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-android-more" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
   </ons-toolbar-button>
</div>
```

You can find a working CodePen example [HERE](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/rOKGKz).

Regarding the `sliding-menu`, it seems working fine.

Comment: Thanks Andi, 
It still doesn't close though.
Even on your codepen example, if I click on one of the two button in the menu, It still doesn't close the popover. I tried on android and on a pc with firefox and chrome.

Comment: This is now solved. I actually thought about why this wasn't working and why the sliding menu had a similar problem. Turns out that I was using onsenui 1.2.2 and I now updated to 1.3.4 and everything works as expected. Thank you fr your help anyway.

Comment: @nocrack you are welcome! Please consider to update to 1.3.11, as it fixes many bugs, and to upvote my answer if you consider it helpful :)