# Onsen UI: Pick list

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

Does Onsen UI support pick lists? I can't find an example. I need to have users select from a list of options. Using the select element would be cleaner. While I can get the select to function the rendering is not consistent with the rest of the UI.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking for this, but I think it's the most similar thing in Onsen UI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27141353/4468962

Answer (score 1):

Onsen UI doesn't provide a pick list element. If you want to implement it you can use the following code, the appearance is similar to Onsen's default theme.

```html
<select class="text-input" ng-model="animationName" ng-init=" animationName = 'select element' ">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
</select>
```